# AOP implemented with the Decorator pattern over a Generic Repository

Tags: design-patterns, aop, decorator, simple-injector, repository-design

I'm trying to build a prototype that applies Aspect Oriented Programming to my project using Decorators.  Some portion of my project will use a generic Repository (for simple CRUD), but eventually I'll also incorporate Command and Query handlers (these will perform specific tasks like ProcessCustomerOrders, etc.).  Also, the cross-cutting concerns I’d like to example here are Security and Logging.

> Also, I know that my example code is not the using the Decorator pattern, but is just an example of the code I have in place for this prototype to provide a context.

I understand there are other ways to implement AOP (or cross-cutting concerns), like Proxy or Code Weaving patterns, but I'm not familiar with these patterns and therefore don't know trade-offs between them.

I'm using a console app here just to show how things will look if I "new" them up in a chained fashion.

My questions are:

> (1) How do I wire this up using Simple Injector (in the bootstrap class) and still keep the ordering the same?
>
> (2) Is this the proper use of the Decorator Pattern (since I'm not using the base abstract or interface class or decorator base)?
>
> (3) Is there a clean way to make use of more than one implementation of a ILogger service (for example DatabaseLogger and ConsoleLogger) in the same Repository without injecting two different versions?
>
> (4) The actual logging is implemented in the Repository method and the ILogger service is injected into the Repository class, but is there a better way to do this than hard wire up the logger and still use Generic Repositories?
>
> (5) Should I be using Proxy or Code Weaving patterns based on how I'm using the Repository in this prototype?

Also, general critiques on this design are welcomed.

Prototype code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var e = new Entity
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Example Entity",
            Description = "Used by Decorators",
            RowGuild = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        Controller controller = 
            new Controller(
                new GenericRepository<Entity>(
                    new ClientManagementContext(), 
                    new ConsoleLogger()
                ), 
                new WebUser()
            );

        controller.Create(e);
    }
}

public static class RepositoryBoostrapper
{
    public static void Bootstrap(Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid RowGuild { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class Controller
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<Entity> _repository;
    private readonly IUserSecurity _userSecurity;

    public Controller(IGenericRepository<Entity> repository, IUserSecurity userSecurity)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _userSecurity = userSecurity;
    }

    // Displays all Entities on a web page view
    public ActionResult Index() {
        IEnumerable<Entity> e = null;
        User user = User.Identity.Name;

        if (_userSecurity.ValidateUser(user))
        {
            e = _repository.ReadTs();
        }
        return View(e);
    }

    public ActionResult Create(Entity e) {
        User user = User.Identity.Name;

        if (_userSecurity.ValidateUser(user))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _repository.CreateT(e);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        return View(e);
    }
}

public interface IGenericRepository<T>
{
    T ReadTById(object id);
    IEnumerable<T> ReadTs();
    void UpdateT(T entity);
    void CreateT(T entity);
    void DeleteT(T entity);
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ClientManagementContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public GenericRepository(ClientManagementContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public T ReadTById(object id) {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ReadTs() {
        return _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable(); 
    }

    public void UpdateT(T entity) {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _logger.Log(typeof(T).Name +
        " executed in " +
        watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
    }

    public void CreateT(T entity) {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _logger.Log(typeof(T).Name +
        " executed in " +
        watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
    }


    public void DeleteT(T entity) {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}



public class Logger
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Logger(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        _logger.Log(message);
    }
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

public class DatabaseLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        // database logging
    }
}

public interface IUserSecurity
{
    bool ValidateUser(User user);
}

public class UserSecurity
{
    private readonly IUserSecurity _userSecurity;

    public UserSecurity(IUserSecurity userSecurity)
    {
        _userSecurity = userSecurity;
    }

    public bool ValidateUser(User user)
    {
        return _userSecurity.ValidateUser(user);
    }
}

public class WebUser : IUserSecurity
{
    public bool ValidateUser(User user)
    {
        // validate MVC user

        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE Based on @Steven's answer:**

Simple Injector DI of Decorators and Repository:

```cs
public static class RepositoryBoostrapper
{
public static void Bootstrap(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
        typeof(IGenericRepository<>),
        typeof(GenericRepository<>));

    container.RegisterDecorator(
        typeof(IGenericRepository<>),
        typeof(LoggingRepositoryDecorator<>));

    container.RegisterDecorator(
        typeof(IGenericRepository<>),
        typeof(SecurityRepositoryDecorator<>));

}
}
```

The order of the Decorator chain as called by the Controller should be Controller (checks) > Security (if OK to proceed then allow call to) > Repo (update the persistence layer and then) > Log (to some facility) > and return back to Controller.

New Controller class:

```cs
public class Controller
{
private readonly IGenericRepository<Entity> securityGenericRepository;

public Controller(
    IGenericRepository<Entity> securityGenericRepository)
{
    this.securityGenericRepository = securityGenericRepository;
}

// Displays all Entities on a web page view
public bool Index() {
    var e = new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Example Entity",
        Description = "Used by Decorators",
        RowGuild = Guid.NewGuid()
    };
    this.securityGenericRepository.CreateT(e);
    return false;
}

public ActionResult Create(Entity e) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        this.securityGenericRepository.CreateT(e);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(e);
}
}
```

Question about the above code excerpt:

If I want to take some action in the Controller based on a return value (for example returning a bool from the Security Decorator), do I then have to modify the IGenericRepository interface (and therefore the GenericRepository class)?  In a way this means, since the Repo and the Security Decorator classes both implement the same interface, if I want to make a change to the return value or parameters of the Security methods, I'll also need to change the Repository methods?

Also, do I only now pass in the Security implementation of the IGenericRepository to the Controller?

Also, the logger has been changed to look like the following:

```cs
public class LoggingRepositoryDecorator<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
{
private readonly IGenericRepository<T> decoratee;
private readonly ILogger logger;

public LoggingRepositoryDecorator(IGenericRepository<T> decoratee, ILogger logger)
{
    this.decoratee = decoratee;
    this.logger = logger;
}

// ...

public void CreateT(T entity)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    this.decoratee.CreateT(entity);

    this.logger.Log(typeof(T).Name + " executed in " +
        watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
}
// ...
}
```

Above, I just call to the Decoratee and add the Decorator's functionality on top.

And finally the Security Decorator:

```cs
public class SecurityRepositoryDecorator<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
{
  private readonly IGenericRepository<T> decoratee;
  private readonly IUserSecurity userSecurity;
  private User user;

  public SecurityRepositoryDecorator(
  IGenericRepository<T> decoratee,
  IUserSecurity userSecurity)
  {
    this.decoratee = decoratee;
    this.userSecurity = userSecurity;
    this.user = User.Identity.Name;
  }

  // ...

  public void CreateT(T entity)
  {
    if (userSecurity.ValidateUser(user))
      this.decoratee.CreateT(entity);
  }
  // ...
  }
```

What I don't understand above is, where/when does the logger get called?

**UPDATE 2:**

Seems to work as the Decorator pattern should now; thanks to Steven for all the great answers.

Prototype Main function:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new Container();
    PrototypeBoostrapper.Bootstrap(container);

    IRepository<Entity> repository = 
        new ValidateUserDecorator<Entity>(
            new LoggingDecorator<Entity>(
                new Repository<Entity>(
                    new PrototypeContext()), 
                new ConsoleLogger()), 
            new ClaimsPrincipal());

    var controller = new Controller(repository);

    var e = new Entity
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Example Entity",
        Description = "Used by Decorators",
        RowGuild = Guid.NewGuid()
    };

    controller.Create(e);
}
```

Validation (Security) Decorator:

```cs
public class ValidateUserDecorator<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> decoratee;
    //private readonly IUserSecurity userSecurity;
    private IPrincipal User { get; set; }

    public ValidateUserDecorator(
        IRepository<T> decoratee,
        IPrincipal principal)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        User = principal;
    }

    //..
    public void CreateT(T entity)
    {
        if (!User.IsInRole("ValidRoleToExecute"))
            throw new ValidationException();
        this.decoratee.CreateT(entity);
    }
    //..
```

Logging Decorator:

```cs
public class LoggingDecorator<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> decoratee;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public LoggingDecorator(IRepository<T> decoratee, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    // ..
    public void CreateT(T entity)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        this.decoratee.CreateT(entity);

        this.logger.Log(typeof(T).Name + " executed in " +
                        watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
    }
    // ..
```

Generic Repository:

```cs
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly PrototypeContext _context;

    public Repository(PrototypeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    //..
    public void CreateT(T entity) {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    //..
```

The Controller:

```cs
public class Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Entity> repository;

    public Controller(
        IRepository<Entity> repository) {
            this.repository = repository;
    }
    // ..
    public bool Create(Entity e) {
        this.repository.CreateT(e);
        return true;
    }
    // ..
```

Comment: Why not look to existing AOP frameworks for inspiration?  Spring.NET has AOP functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dave, I'll have a look at that framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> (1) How do I wire this up using Simple Injector (in the bootstrap
>   class) and still keep the ordering the same,

Simple Injector contains a **RegisterDecorator** method that can be used to register decorators. Registered decorators are (guaranteed to be) applied in the order in which they are registered. Example:

```cs
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IGenericRepository<>), 
    typeof(GenericRepository<>));

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IGenericRepository<>), 
    typeof(LoggingRepositoryDecorator<>));

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IGenericRepository<>), 
    typeof(SecurityRepositoryDecorator<>));
```

This configuration ensures that every time an `IGenericRepository<T>` is requested, an `GenericRepository<T>` is returned which is wrapped with an `LoggingRepository<T>` which is wrapped by an `SecurityRepository<T>`. The last registered decorator will be the outer-most decorator.

> (2) Is this the proper use of the Decorator Pattern (since I'm not
>   using the base abstract or interface class or decorator base)

I'm not sure how you're currently doing things; I don't see any decorators in your code. But one thing is wrong. Your `GenericRepository<T>` uses the `ILogger`, but logging is a cross-cutting concern. It should be placed in a decorator. That decorator might look like this:

```cs
public LoggingRepositoryDecorator<T> : IGenericRepository<T> {
    private IGenericRepository<T> decoratee;
    private ILogger _logger;

    public LoggingRepositoryDecorator(IGenericRepository<T> decoratee,
        ILogger logger) {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public T ReadTById(object id) { return this.decoratee.ReadTById(id); }
    public IEnumerable<T> ReadTs() { return this.decoratee.ReadTs(); }

    public void UpdateT(T entity) {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        this.decoratee.UpdateT(entity);

        _logger.Log(typeof(T).Name + " executed in " + 
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");    
    }

    public void CreateT(T entity)  {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        this.decoratee.CreateT(entity); 

        _logger.Log(typeof(T).Name + " executed in " + 
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");    
    }

    public void DeleteT(T entity) { this.decoratee.DeleteT(entity); }
}
```

> (3) Is there a clean way to make use of more than one implementation
>   of a ILogger service (for example DatabaseLogger and ConsoleLogger) in
>   the same Repository without injecting two different versions?

It depends on your needs, but either the [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) or the [Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) might be of help here. The Composite pattern allows you to hide a collection of 'things' behind an interface of that thing. For instance:

```cs
public class CompositeLogger : ILogger {
    private readonly IEnumerable<ILogger> loggers;

    public CompositeLogger(IEnumerable<ILogger> loggers) {
        this.loggers = loggers;
    }

    public void Log(string message) {
        foreach (var logger in this.loggers) {
            logger.Log(message);
        }        
    }    
}
```

You can register this as follows:

```cs
// Register an IEnumerable<ILogger>
container.RegisterCollection<ILogger>(new[] {
    typeof(DatabaseLogger), 
    typeof(ConsoleLogger)
});

// Register an ILogger (the CompositeLogger) that depends on IEnumerable<ILogger>
container.Register<ILogger, CompositeLogger>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

With the proxy pattern on the other hand you could hide some decision about how to root the message inside the proxy. Example:

```cs
public class LoggerSelector : ILogger {
    private readonly ILogger left;
    private readonly ILogger right;

    public LoggerSelector(ILogger left, ILogger right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public void Log(string message) {
        var logger = this.SelectLogger(message);
        logger.Log(message);
    }

    private ILogger SelectLogger(string message) {
        return message.Contains("fatal") ? this.left : this.right;
    }
}
```

You can register this as follows:

```cs
container.Register<ConsoleLogger>();
container.Register<DatabaseLogger>();

container.Register<ILogger>(() => new LoggerSelector(
    left: container.GetInstance<ConsoleLogger>(),
    right: container.GetInstance<DatabaseLogger>());
```

> (4) The actual logging is implemented in the Repository method and the
>   ILogger service is injected into the Repository class, but is there a
>   better way to do this than hard wire up the logger and still use
>   Generic Repositories?

Absolutely: don't inject the logger into the repository, since this is a cross-cutting concern. You will probably be changing the logging logic much sooner than you will change the rest of the generic repository code. So you should write a decorator instead.

Happily, since you created a generic interface for your repositories, you will only have to write one generic decorator for adding logging behavior to repositories. Unfortunately, since the repository interface has 5 members, your decorators will need to implement all of them. But you can't blame decorators for this; it's the [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) itself that violates the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

**UPDATE:**

> private readonly IGenericRepository securityGenericRepository;

You shouldn't name your repository like this. Security and logging are cross-cutting concerns and the consumer should not have to know about their existence. What if you decide you need an extra cross-cutting concern that should be triggered before the security goes off? Are you going to rename all your `securityGenericRepository` dependencies to `fooGenericRepository`? That would defeat the whole purpose of having decorators: they allow you to plug in new cross-cutting concerns dynamically, without having to change a single line of code in your application.

> If I want to take some action in the Controller based on a return value

Think hard if that really is what you need. Especially for security. At that level you should usually only want to check and throw an exception. You don't want to catch such exception in your controllers, let alone that you want to return a value.

Such a security decorator is usually meant as safety mechanism to prevent evil doers from doing bad things with your system. Throwing `SecurityException` is the right thing to do. Such exception will be logged and will be picked up by your team or by support. What you are probably trying to do is to show users a friendly message when they clicked a button that their current role doesn't allow, but instead you should prevent showing this button to the user.

And you might still show the user a friendly message by implementing the `Application_Error` event and checking whether a `SecurityException` was thrown and redirecting the user to a page that explains that they unfortunately tried to accessed a page that the system didn't allow access to. But IMO, if the user sees that page, they either are 'hacking' the system, or you made a programming mistake.

Please remember that a decorator implements the same abstraction as it wraps. This means that you can't change the abstraction (and can't return something different) with an decorator. If this is what you need, your consumer will have to depend on something different. But please note that this is not a very common scenario, so you have to think really hard if this really is what you need.

In a system I'm working on right now, my Windows forms classes depend on an `IPromptableCommandHandler<TCommand>` instead of `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`. That's because we wanted to show a dialog to the user that explained that the data they entered was invalid (some data can only be validated by the server) and besides the command, we pass in a delegate that allows the 'promptable command handler' to call back in case the command was handled successfully. The promptable command handler implementation itself depends on an `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` and delegates the work and catches any `ValidationException` that are returned from the `WCF` service. This prevents each form from having an ugly try-catch block. Still the solution isn't really nice, and I will change when I got a better solution.

But still, even with such solution, you probably still want to create a decorator that does security and have a proxy (the promptable command handler in my case) that contains the catch statement. Don't try to return something different from a decorator.

> What I don't understand above is, where/when does the logger get called?

The registration with the two decorators ensures that when a `IGenericRepositotory<Customer>` is requested, the following object graph is constructed:

```cs
IGenericRepository<Customer> repository =
    new SecurityRepositoryDecorator<Customer>(
        new LoggingRepositoryDecorator<Customer>(
            new GenericRepository<Customer>(
                new ClientManagementContext()),
            DatabaseLogger(),
        new AspNetUserSecurity());
```

When a controller calls the repository `Create` method, the following call chain will be executed:

```
Begin SecurityRepositoryDecorator<Customer>.Create (calls `userSecurity.ValidateUser`)
    Begin LoggingRepositoryDecorator.Create (calls `Stopwatch.StartNew()`)
        Begin GenericRepository<Customer>.Create
        End GenericRepository<Customer>.Create
    End LoggingRepositoryDecorator.Create (calls ` this.logger.Log`)
End SecurityRepositoryDecorator<Customer>.Create
```

So, the security decorator calls the logging decorator, because security decorator wraps the logging decorator (and the logging decorator wraps the `GenericRepository<T>`).

ps. Your method naming for the repository is really ugly. Here are some tips:

- Call the interface `IRepository<T>` instead of `IGenericRepository<T>` (because `T` implies that it is in fact generic).
- Remove all the `T` postfixes from the methods; they have no meaning when you define closed repositories. For instance, what does `IRepository<Customer>.CreateT` do? What is 'T' in the context of an `IRepository<Customer>`? A better name would be `CreateCustomer`, but that is not possible, because `IRepository<Order>.CreateCustomer` wouldn't make any sense. By naming it `IRepository<T>.Create` all those problems go away.

Comment: How does the handle to _logger.Log(message); in LoggingRepositoryDecorator.Update() method get set since it's not injected?  Should ILogger be injected into the LogginRepositoryDecorator<T> class?

Comment: @Aaron: Sorry, I forgot to inject it. Updated my answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Also, if I want to stack the decorators, for example, When I make the call to the Create() method in the Repository from the Controller class, I want to first check that the user has permission to make the call to Create(), then log that they made the call to Create(), then actually make the call to Create() like so Controller >> SecurityGenericRepository.ValidateUser(user) >> LogginingGenericRepository.Log(message) >> GenericRepository.Create(entity).  How do I stack the calls in the Controller?  Do I need to call the LoggingGenericRepository in the Security class?

Comment: As it looks like it's wired up by this call to the container: container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IGenericRepository<>), 
    typeof(SecurityRepositoryDecorator<>)); the SecurityRepositoryDecorator<> class actually would make a call into the Repository directly?  Should I have a Security Decorator that calls the Repo directly, and a Security Decorator that calls the Logger directly, so I have the option to "stack" the Decorators?

Comment: @Aaron: Stacking the decorators is a matter of registering them in the right order. You just inject the `UserSecurity` into the `SecurityRepositoryDecorator` and make sure this decorator is registered after the `LoggingRepositoryDecorator`.

Comment: @Aaron: Decorators should not know anything about the thing they decorate, except of course that it is an implementation of that interface. This allows you to stack decorators in any way you like and change it later on without breaking anything. So the security decorator just calls the `decoratee` and in your configuration this happens to be the logging decorator, but the security decorator neither knows or cares. The same holds for the logging decorator.

Comment: I updated the question with code that seems to work so far.  Thanks for all the great answers.