# How to move validation handling from a controller action to a decorator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, decorator, simple-injector

## Maintenance Edit

After using this approach for a while I found myself only adding the exact same boilerplate code in every controller so I decided to do some reflection magic. In the meantime I ditched using MVC for my views - Razor is just so tedious and ugly - so I basically use my handlers as a JSON backend. The approach I currently use is to decorate my queries/commands with a `Route` attribute that is located in some common assembly like this:

```cs
[Route("items/add", RouteMethod.Post)]
public class AddItemCommand { public Guid Id { get; set; } }

[Route("items", RouteMethod.Get)]
public class GetItemsQuery : IQuery<GetItemsResponse> { }

// The response inherits from a base type that handles
// validation messages and the like
public class GetItemsResponse : ServiceResponse { }
```

I then implemented an MVC host that extracts the annotated commands/queries and generates the controllers and handlers for me at startup time. With this my application logic is finally free of MVC cruft. The query responses are also automatically populated with validation messages. My MVC applications now all look like this:

```
+ MvcApp
  +- Global.asax
  +- Global.asax.cs - Startup the host and done
  +- Web.config
```

After realizing I really don't use MVC outside the host - and constantly having issues with the bazillion dependencies the framework has - I implemented another host based on [NServiceKit](https://github.com/NServiceKit/NServiceKit). Nothing had to be changed in my application logic and the dependencies are down to `System.Web`, `NServiceKit` and `NServiceKit.Text` that takes good care of the model binding. I know it's a very similar approach to how `NServiceKit/ServiceStack` does their stuff but I'm now totally decoupled from the web framework in use so in case a better one comes along I just implement another host and that's it.

## The situation

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC site that's implementing the businesslogic-view separation via the [IQueryHandler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) and [ICommandHandler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) abstractions (using [the almighty SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org) for dependency injection).

## The Problem

I've got to attach some custom validation logic to a `QueryHandler` via a decorator and that's working pretty well in and of itself. The problem is that in the event of validation errors I want to be able to show the same view that the action would have returned but with information on the validation error of course. Here is a sample for my case:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<SomeQuery, SomeTransport> queryHandler;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var dto = this.queryHandler.Handle(new SomeQuery { /* ... */ });
            // Doing something awesome with the data ...
            return this.View(new HomeViewModel());
        }
        catch (ValidationException exception)
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelErrors(exception);
            return this.View(new HomeViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

In this scenario I have some business logic that's handled by the `queryHandler` that is decorated with a `ValidationQueryHandlerDecorator` that throws `ValidationException`s when it is appropriate.

### What I want it to do

What I want is something along the lines of:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<SomeQuery, SomeTransport> queryHandler;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var dto = this.queryHandler.Handle(new SomeQuery { /* ... */ });
        // Doing something awesome with the data ...
        // There is a catch-all in place for unexpected exceptions but
        // for ValidationExceptions I want to do essentially the same
        // view instantiation but with the model errors attached
        return this.View(new HomeViewModel());
    }
}
```

I've been thinking about a special `ValidationErrorHandlerAttribute` but then I'm losing the context and I can't really return the proper view. The same goes with the approach where I just wrap the `IQueryHandler<,>` with a decorator... I've seen some strange pieces of code that did some string sniffing on the route and then instantiating a new controller and viewmodel via `Activator.CreateInstance` - that doesn't seem like a good idea.

So I'm wondering whether there is a nice way to do this ... maybe I just don't see the wood from the trees. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to make the action method oblivious to this, since the action method is in control of the returned view model, and in case of a validation exception you need to return a view model with all the actual data (to prevent the user from losing his changes). What you might be able to do however to make this more convenient is add an extension method for executing queries in an action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = this.queryHandler.ValidatedHandle(this.ModelState, new SomeQuery { });

    if (result.IsValid) {
        return this.View(new HomeViewModel(result.Data));
    }
    else
    {
        return this.View(new HomeViewModel());
    }
}
```

The `ValidatedHandle` extension method could look like this:

```
public static ValidatedResult<TResult> ValidatedHandle<TQuery, TResult>(
    this IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler,
    TQuery query, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    try
    {
        return new ValidatedResult<TResult>.CreateValid(handler.Handle(query));
    }
    catch (ValidationException ex)
    {
        modelState.AddModelErrors(ex);
        return ValidatedResult<TResult>.Invalid;
    }
}
```

Do note that you should only catch such validation exception if the validation is on data that the user has entered. If you send a query with parameters that are set programmatically, a validation exception simply means a programming error and you should blog up, log the exception and show a friendly error page to the user.

Comment: That's a nice touch, I did indeed consider an extension method on the controller but not on the `IQueryHandler`, I'll give it a try. Thanks again!

Comment: @vanhelgen: On a win forms project I recently did, instead of injecting our `ICommandHandler<T>` we injected an `IPromptableCommandHandler<T>` (I talked about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527589/264697)). The implementation caught the exception and showed it to the user. Using the extension method is almost the same. We defined a new abstraction, because the implementation needed some extra services that would otherwise needed to be passed on by the caller.

Comment: I've been toying around with this and I also can't see a better approach than yours so I that's what I'll be using now. Thank you for the advise and the `IPromptableCommandHandler<T>` link. I already have functionality in place to inform the user of validation errors but I'll keep it in mind for the future. Always a pleasure :-)