# ninject inject iunitofwork to repository scoped attribute

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ninject, unit-of-work, irepository

Let me start with my current setup, and then explain what I am trying to achieve. We are using NHibernate and trying to implement the IRepository/IUnitOfWork pattern with Ninject. It should ideally work generically for whatever application is using the code, whether is ASP.Net, WCF or something else.

IUnitOfWork

```cs
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    object Add(object obj);//all other supported CRUD operations we want to expose
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

UnitOfWork

```cs
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private readonly ITransaction _transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public object Add(object obj)
    {
        return _session.Save(obj);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if(!_transaction.IsActive)
        {throw new Exception("some error");}
        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (!_transaction.IsActive)
        {
            throw new Exception("some other error");
        }
        _transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

IRepository

```cs
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class
{
    TId Add(TEntity item);//add other missing CRUD operations
}
```

GenericRepository

```cs
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public TId Add(TEntity item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am using Ninject as my IOC container. The goal is to reuse the same IUnitOfWork for the life cycle of the creating of the UnitOfWork. I want the life cycle that is implemented to work no matter what the calling application is, or else I would have just used InRequestScope like most suggestions online.
I was able to do something like this:

```cs
//constructor
public MyService(IUnitOfWork uow, IRepository<User, int> userRepo, IRepository<Cat, int> catRepo)
{
    _uow = uow; _userRepo = userRepo; _catRepo = catRepo;
}

//method in same class
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    _userRepo.Add(someUser);
    _catRepo.Add(someCat);
    _uow.Commit();

    //rollback on error
}
```

And my bindings are set up like:

```cs
Bind<IUnitOfWork>.To<UnitOfWork>().InCallScope();
Bind(typeof(IRepository<,>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<,>));
```

And this binding configuration actually works for the above `MyService`, it will create the UnitOfWork once in the constructor and it will use that same UnitOfWork for the IRepo impls as well, no matter how many layers down they may actually be.

But what I would like to be able to do is hide the IUnitOfWork away from the applications altogether. I would rather provide some TransactionAttribute that can be placed on top of a method and it will create the IUnitOfWork on entry and that same instance will be injected to all any future requests for an IUnitOfWork within the scope of the TransactionAttribute. And it would take care of committing and rollingback accordingly. So the previous code would become something like this:

```cs
//constructor
public MyService(IRepository<User, int> userRepo, IRepository<Cat, int> catRepo)
{
    _uow = uow; _userRepo = userRepo; _catRepo = catRepo;
}

//method in same class
[Transaction]
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    _userRepo.Add(someUser);
    _catRepo.Add(someCat);
}
```

Is there any kind of binding setup I can do that will enable me to mark a method with a [Transaction] like this? I am open to some minor restructuring of the IUnitOfWork and IRepository stuff, and the Service layer code is just scrap code so I can be very flexible there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, injecting won't work with

```
[Transaction]
public void DoSomeWork()
{
      _userRepo.Add(someUser);
      _catRepo.Add(someCat);
}
```

after all, the container can't know what kind of method you're going to call and when you're going to call it.

Taking things further, since you want it to work with WebApps, WCF,.. maybe some quartz job or what not: You'll have to decide whether you want to tie the lifetime of an `IUnitOfWork` / `Repository` / NHibernate `Session` to the lifetime of the objects which use it (like `MyService`) or if you want a service to live longer (for example a singleton) and create a new NHibernate `Session` for for a method call like:

```
[Transaction]
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    _userRepo.Add(someUser);
    _catRepo.Add(someCat);
}
```

This could actually probably be achieved by [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), either using [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) or [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/). Alternatively you could also look into using the decorator pattern to achieve this (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526474/aop-implemented-with-the-decorator-pattern-over-a-generic-repository)). However if i remember correctly ninject currently lacks some of the niceties to support easz decorator handling.

Alternatively to the `[Transaction]` attribute you could start with controlling everything explicitly:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IUnitOfWorkSession Begin(); // starts a session and transaction
}

public interface IUnitOfWorkSession : IDisposable
{
   void Commit();
   void Dispose(); // performs rollback in case no commit was performed
}
```

Since you will need to access the nhibernate `Session` in other objects, like `_userRepo` and `_catRepo` you'll also need a way to access the `Session` there independent from the container, since it got nothing to do with how/when you instantiate the objects.
Of course, you could pass it along like:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    using(IUnitOfWorkSession session = _unitOfWork.Begin())
    {    
        _userRepo.Add(session, someUser);
        _catRepo.Add(session, someCat);
        session.Commit();
    }
}
```

But that's not really cool. So instead you will need to use something like a `ThreadLocal` (if you're using async/await this could be problematic) or otherwise a `SynchronizationContext`-local storage.

Now if you've managed to get this far you can look into doing AOP.
AOP would have two handle two things:

- getting access to the IUnitOfWork.

  - could be done by weaving it as additional ctor argument
  - or it could check if there is already one, if there is, it could use this one, if not, it could either throw or weave the argument in...
- wrapping the decorated method like with the same code as above:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    using(IUnitOfWorkSession session = _unitOfWork.Begin()) // weave this
    {    
        _userRepo.Add(session, someUser);
        _catRepo.Add(session, someCat);
        session.Commit(); // weave this
    }
}
```

Comment: We currently use `PostSharp` (v2.1 sadly) in other components, so I know I would use that to achieve AOP. I get the idea that the OnEntry for my aspect would begin a new `UnitOfWork` (I'll ignore trying to attach to an existing one), but how would I make sure that the created `UnitOfWork` is the one injected for each `IRepository`? Would I have to do this by sticking the aspect's `UnitOfWork` on to some kind of context mechanism (ThreadLocal/SynchronizationContext like you mentioned)?

Comment: Since (at least that's what i'm interpeting) you can't or don't want to tie the lifecycle of a `Session` to that of the objects using it, you'll indeed need to use a context mechanism like ThreadLocal or SynchronizationContext.

Comment: If you don't want to use such a context mechanism you would need to create a new user repo, cat repo etc. each time you execute `DoSomeWork`. You might end up re-creating quite a big portion of your object graph (depends on the design...). With the context mechanism you only create the `Session`, but you still need to do that (by `IUnitOfWork.Begin()` or creating a new `IUnitOfWork` instance).

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I am going to go the route of AOP and create my Session in my aspect and store it on some context for later.